# How do I get every program that connects to the internet to do so through my VPN?

Tags: java, vpn, jdk, android-studio, tor

I've been trying to install the Android Studio app for **5** days.

But I have not succeeded so far.

To install Android, you need to install Java.

And when I want to install Java, this message shows:

```
Downloading Oracle Java 8 ...
--2018-09-27 06: 24: 29-- http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com) ... 2.18.35.31
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com) | 2.18.35.31 |: 80 ... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response ... 403 Forbidden
2018-09-27 06:24:29 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 installed oracle-java8-installer package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
```

Later I realized that because I live in Iran, our Oracle site has filtered us and I cannot install it.

When I use the VPN, they only put the browser in their network.

Is there a solution to this problem?

How do I get any app that connects to the internet to use the Tor network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install java from alternate source such as webupd8team PPA or official Ubuntu PPAs

https://medium.com/@aashimad1/install-android-studio-in-ubuntu-b8aed675849f

Also: how to install OpenJDK java using apt-get.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Can you mark it as answered?

Comment: OK.The second link helped fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Launch a VPS server somewhere else using a cloud provider and setup SSH keys so that you can execute `ssh foo@1.2.3.4` where `foo` is a user and `1.2.3.4` is the IP address of the VPS. Now that SSH works you can setup the tunnel using:

```
sudo apt-get install sshuttle
sudo sshuttle -r foo@1.2.3.4 0.0.0.0/0 -vv --dns
```

Comment: You can try a free VPN as well.

Comment: I can't find the free service to support all the computer traffic. If you know, please send it a link?